# How to Iterate over the ASCII characters with LC3 laguage?

Tags: lc3

Please write machine code following this outline:

Initialize index to zero
Iterate over the ASCII characters until the null terminator (zero) is found
Add the index to the current character being processed
Output the result of the previous statement as an ASCII character
Increment the index
Halt

This is a question on my homework, and it requires only the language of LC3 to traverse and find 0. I want to know how to load ASCII files into the program using only basic languages such as (AND/ADD/LD/LEA/LDI/LDR...)?

Answer (score 1):

Put a string into memory like so:

```
STR1 .stringz "Hello"
```

then you can load the string and set R1 to point to it:

```
LEA R1, STR1 ;R1 points to STR1
```

Now R1 is equivelent to the Ascii code for "H", R1 + 1 would be ascii for "e". Then you just need some looping and comparisons until you know R1 = 0.
Remember that .Stringz will put a Null terminating string into memory.